# Optocoupler relay, one power source for both relay and microcontroller

Tags: relay, opto-isolator, isolation, esp32

I'm having a project, there will be a 16 relays (Lights), which are controlled by 16 buttons. I'm using esp32 as Micro-controller.

For achieving this, I've used two mcp23017 boards as GPIO extenders. Everything works perfect. The thing is, I want to use one power source for both relays and esp32+mcps. So now that "opto isolation" is gone as i understand.

For protecting my esp and mcp boards, what kind of components i can use ? I want to minimize the noise, make it more stable for circumstances.

Sorry for my poor drawing, but i hope that you will get the idea.
(For the buttons, to minimize the drawing i just drawed one of them)
(For the second relay, to minimize drawing i just supplied one 12v to output side, but all of them are connected to outputs)

Parts list:

1. [Buck converter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LSEBYHU)
2. [MCP23017](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086C4J549)
3. [Relay Unit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KTELP3I)

[image]

Comment: What protection you are after? From what you need protection?

Comment: The relay contacts are of course still isolated from the relay coils. Why do you have multiple relay boards in your circuit, by the way?

Comment: @Justme I mean people are saying that for "opto-isolation" you have to use two different power source, since im using one, i just wanted take people's opinion regarding if the circuit is fine like this, or there are anything i can do to improve it. (To make it more stable/convenient , to protect esp's from spikes etc)

Comment: well, to protect it from inductive spikes, you'll need separate power supplies. That you already know.

Comment: @JonathanS. I'm planning to put ESP+MCP+"Small relay" in a box in house somewhere, and the 12V relays will be "remote relays" which will be located  next to the lights, they will be spreaded in the house. I'm expecting to have 30-40 meters max distance between small relay and remote relay, do you think it is fine ? Or i should approach in different way ?

Comment: Just about the relay board ... If you are using it with 220 V main, verify that the "bottom" and/or "top" wiring complies with the "isolation rules" ... On some boards, you need desoldering one relay to see the wiring below. If the PCB is cut around the "power pins" to isolate the "coil pins", it may be ok.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've seen something like this [link](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-eliminate-ground-loops-with-signal-isolation) They are saying that DC-DC converted called "DCH010505" would give you and isolated 5V and GND. My knowledge get stuck. Can you please comment about if it would make any sense for my case or not ?

Comment: @Antonio51 Sorry Antonio, i didn't understand what you mean (i guess because of my lack knowledge) . Can you please elaborate it ?

Comment: @signalz Who says you have to use different power supplies if you have an opto-isolator? The opto-isolator is mostly a kind of cargo-cult gimmick with these devices. If the board allows it, then it is a designed-in feature to use same power supplies. Besides, the relays need 5V supply, the control may work with 3.3V supply. However, if the ESP32 has 3.3V I2C bus, you need to use the GPIO expander at 3.3V too, unless there is a level converter somewhere in the system.

Comment: @Justme [link](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17392173/69567236-ade27800-0f97-11ea-8b1d-bbeac50c928a.jpg) As i see MCP is compatible with 5v and 3.3v in. I've feeded the both button mcp and relay mcp with 5v, so far its stable. So for the overall circuit design, do you think it is fine ?

Comment: @signalz Sure the MCP is compatible with both supply voltages. It just requires that the I2C bus voltage matches the supply voltage. So if you power it with 5V and ESP32 IO is 3.3V, the MCP does not work and if MCP board has pull-ups to 5V it might damage the ESP32. This is why you always should know exactly what you bought and with schematics to verify the seller claims.

Comment: @Justme i see your point, thanks for warning. As you said ESP32 is 3.3V and MCP23017 can work with 3.3/5.0V but since im feeding it with 5V there might be inconsistency. It was working fine like this and never checked it ! :) Thanks again i will fix it. Apart from this, do you see any other point that i should consider ? Thanks

Comment: @signalz  what I mean is this ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsnmh.jpg The three power pins of the relay are well isolated from all the other parts of the board through an air 
 "channel" ...

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed you want to stretch wires 40m. That's really far. It is possible to pick up noise and ground loops on the wires that will make the connections unreliable.

As a solution, I just found out you can buy a packet of 10 esp8266 wifi cards for around 30 dollars from amazon. Seems like just the ticket for you. Then, you control everything locally. These things will run off of cheapo 5V usb adapters. Here is a link to the amazon page:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08QZ2887K/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08QZ2887K)

You could still keep the esp32 as the main controller, and connect via wifi to the sub controllers, all without the annoying possibility of ground loops or noise. You can program the esp8266 with arduino, python, or various other languages.

You can then drive the relay boards with transistors that are driven by an esp8266 GPIO. Here is a link to a page that describes how to do it with discrete relays. The relay board may have the diode already built in.

http://electronicsbeliever.com/how-to-drive-a-relay-with-a-mosfet/

Remember to use a "Logic Level" mosfet, or it won't work with esp8266, which outputs 3.3V on it's gpio ports (ISTR). You could also use an NPN transistor instead of a MOSFET, since they are pretty much guaranteed to work with a 3.3V system.

Edit: added the fact that esp8266 cards do wifi.

Edit 2: Use ESP-Now protocol. Watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkHdk_mKGUw

Comment: please don't Answer comments. I read "30-40 meters max distance between small relay and remote relay" so the 40 m wires will be 12 V.